# How to use Rotation and Translation for an Image simultaneously in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

I using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation for the Rotation of an Image and CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation for the Translation of an Image. This is my code:

```
-(void)rotateTranslate
{
    r++;
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(r);
    imageView.transform = transform;
    x++;
    y++;
    CGAffineTransform transform1=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x,y);
    imageView.transform= transform1;
    [self performSelector:@selector(rotateTranslate) withObject:self afterDelay:0.2];
}
```

My Problem is the Image  is only Translating it is not Rotating. If I use the Rotate and Translate separately means it works Pretty well. How can I modify my code to work both well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are making an individual rotation and then translation and setting it. So the rotation is overridden by the translation. You must do something like this,

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imageView.transform, 1);
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 1, 1);

imageView.transform= transform;

[self performSelector:@selector(rotateTranslate) withObject:self afterDelay:0.2];
```

But this will not animate the rotation. It will just jump from the current transform to the end transform.

And you don't seem to have an end point defined.

Comment: Thanks.. Its working well... I will accept this answer within 5 minutes :)